# Jetpack Compose: Modify Room data class using TextField

Tags: android, kotlin, state, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Modifying simple values and `data class`es using `EditText` is fairly straight forward, and generally looks like this:

```
data class Person(var firstName: String, var lastName: Int)

// ...

val (person, setPerson) = remember { mutableStateOf(Person()) }

// common `onChange` function handles both class properties, ensuring maximum code re-use
fun <T> onChange(field: KMutableProperty1<Person, T>, value: T) {
    val nextPerson = person.copy()
    field.set(nextPerson, value)
    setPerson(nextPerson)
}

// text field for first name
TextField(
    value = person.firstName,
    onChange = { it -> onChange(Person::firstName, it) })

// text field for last name name
TextField(
    value = person.lastName,
    onChange = { it -> onChange(Person::lastName, it) })
```

As you can see, the code in this example is highly reusable: thanks to Kotlin's reflection features, we can use a single `onChange` function to modify every property in this class.

However, a problem arises when the `Person` class is not instantiated from scratch, but rather pulled from disk via `Room`. For example, a `PersonDao` might contain a `findOne() function like so:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM peopleTable WHERE id=:personId LIMIT 1")
fun findOne(personId: String): LiveData<Person>
```

However, you cannot really use this LiveData in a `remember {}` for many reasons:

1. While `LiveData` has a function called `observeAsState()`, it returns `State<T>` and not `MutableState<T>`, meaning that you cannot modify it with the `TextFields`. As such this does not work:

   - `remember { personFromDb.observeAsState()}`
2. You cannot `.copy()` the `Person` that you get from your database because your component will render before the Room query is returned, meaning that you cannot do this, because the `Person` class instance will be remembered as `null`:

   - `remember { mutableStateOf(findPersonQueryResult.value) }`

Given that, what is the proper way to handle this? Should the component that contains the `TextField`s be wrapped in another component that handles the Room query, and only displays the form when the query is returned? What would that look like with this case of `LiveData<Person>`?

Comment: To point 2: you could use remember(yourState [e.g personFromDb.observeAsState()]) {mutableStateOf(findPersonQueryResult.value)} when your state changes the calculation is done again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it with a copy and an immutable data class

```
typealias PersonID = Long?
@Entity
data class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val personID: PersonID = null
}
//VM or sth
object VM {
    val liveData: LiveData<Person> = MutableLiveData() // your db call
    val personDao: PersonDao? = null // Pretending it exists
}

@Dao
abstract class PersonDao {
    abstract fun upsert(person: Person)
}

@Composable
fun test() {
    val personState = VM.liveData.observeAsState(Person("", ""))
    TextField(
        value = personState.value.firstName,
        onValueChange = { fName -> VM.personDao?.upsert(personState.value.copy(firstName = fName))}
    )
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing the same, but this triggers an upsert on every keystroke... Surely there must be another way? I can't sleep at night knowing that my app does that.

Comment: Get a second state and save your data there first and just upsert when you want to conditionally. For example from the keyboard the next button or on the focus changed event or a separate button.